# What, exactly, happens when a task is forked?

Tags: java, multithreading, fork, fork-join

I already understand that forking and joining are used for multithreading, but I don't understand what, exactly happens when a task is forked.  Does forking a task cause that forked task to go back to the beginning of the compute method?  Or does the task do something else?  If I want a task to jump to a different method other than compute and run that when forked, how would I tell it to do that?  Is there some sort of extension to `(instance).fork();` that I can include to specify this?

Answer (score 0):

The task that uses fork/join framework actually gets `split` into smaller subtasks recursively, so they can be executed concurrently.
By forking, each subtask can be executed by a different CPU parallelly, or by different threads on the same CPU.
After the execution of all subtasks is finished, the `join` part begins.
In this process, the results of all the subtasks are recursively joined into a single result.
This whole process happens 'behind the scenes' and can be implemented using a pool of threads called `ForkJoinPool` which manages threads of type `ForkJoinWorkerThread`.

Comment: What happens to those subtasks when the task is forked?  Do they immediately start executing some other function, or do they need to be called upon to do anything with them?  Can you explain a little more fully?

Comment: Can you give an example of how those individual threads can be executed?  I don't quite understand yet.  What I'm trying to get at is where in the code the forked threads go to.  I'm not sure if the forked threads start the compute method over again or if they sit idly until called upon.

Comment: Just figured out the answer to my own question through some extra experimentation.  When fork() is applied to a thread, that thread then gets kicked back to the beginning of the compute method and runs through that.  This can be modified by using either a dummy variable or an existing variable paired with an if/else statement to send this new thread to a different method.